What is this 3 terminal white + grey surface mount device?
What is the surface mount component in this photo?

The dimensions are approximately 2 mm x 3 mm.
Markings look like a reversed 1 and S, or maybe SJ if read from the other direction.
This is from a brushless motor electronic speed controller: product page
Full view of top of PCB for context:

Side view of PCB:


The marking is probably N S where the N was a little misaligned and missed the printable surface.

+1 for a well formed component identification question!

It's a ceramic resonator.
It's used as the clock source for the ATmega8 MCU.
